# Scroll bars on DB grids - seeking a definitive approach

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, tdbgrid, tms

I see lots of DB scroll bar questions, but never seem to find a definitive answer to this one.

There is no option (property) to add/hide DB grid scroll bars, either singly or jointly. The simply auto-appear when needed.

If I don't have enough rows to scroll, I would like my columns to fill the entire grid.

If I design it so then when a vertical scroll bar is added at run-time a horizontal scrollbar is auto-added too (since I just covered the right part of the right most column with a vertical scroll bar, we now need a horizontal scroll bar to see what I am covering).

One option is to design my grid such that there is enough space at the right hand size (how many pixels?) to accommodate a vertical scroll, but that is unsightly until there are enough rows to trigger a scroll bar (if ever).

It seems to me that the most aesthetically pleasing way would be start with a grid which is filled with columns at X pixels wide and increase its width to X + `width of vertical scroll bar` (or decrease the width of one/some of the grids columns by a total of `width of vertical scroll bar`) pixels when adding a new row causes the vertical scrollbar to appear.

Am I missing something? Is there a “correct” way to do this, or an industry standard way (I am **not** asking for a “best” way or anything too subjective, so please don’t close. I believe that a lot of people need to know this).

Is there anything in the standard `TDBgrid` to facilitate this?

Bonus: I subscribe to TMS components, so if there is a way to do this simply with `TAdvDbgrid`, that would be fine for me, but a general solution with `TDBgrid` would be fine.

Non-subjective question: Given that
 - I do not want to increase the width of my `TDBgrid`
 - and that I do not want a blank white column at the right when no vertical scroll bar is present
 - and that I am willing to decrease the width of my right-most column in order to avoid a horizontal scroll bar appearing when a vertical scroll bar appears
... how do I do so?

---

[Update]
Ken was rightly awarded the answer becuse his solution is best for most users.

For those like me who already paid for a TMS subscription, I just noticed that their `TDbAdvgrid` component has a ScrollBars property and when I set it to `ssVertical`, it does what I want.

Now, if I could only figure out a good way to have fixed header row when it is the only row ...

Comment: TJvDBGrid (from the JEDI JVCL) has this capability, and it's source is available. Perhaps a look at that might help?

Comment: +1 Thanks, as always, Ken. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TJvDBGrid (part of the JEDI [JVCL](http://delphi-jedi.org)) has this capability built in, and includes source code. It should be able to either do what you need, or give you the details needed to implement your own descendant.

Comment: Thanks, as always, Ken. JEDI has so much, but it is (if I undertsand correctly) an all or nothing installation. I think it might be time to bite the bullet, though.